# How do we memorize ordered lists?

Tags: memory, long-term-memory, short-term-memory

We have to memorize a lot of ordered lists in life and in our education period.
In chemistry, we memorize the **Metal Reactivity Series** and **Periodic Table**.

Being a table tennis player myself, I can remember the ranking lists of players so well, so effortlessly.

What has research revealed regarding how contents of an ordered list affect how easily it can be memorized, let's say, in the area of education?

**Note: Ordered list is a kind of list were the order in which the items are placed in the list is important.** e.g. The order of American Presidents, the order of British Monarchs...

I am not an expert in psychology. So, please edit the question, if needed.

Comment: Remembering ranking players in single player sports should be relatively easy shouldn't it when you consider the top players have been playing for a fair while and therefore you will know them and their compared abilities?

Comment: I have, on this rare occasion, edited the question to make it more generalised.  This is because it has no bearing on any mental health issues I can see.  If it was, I would have left the question alone and kept it closed as [we can not, and will not, give advice or potential diagnoses for any specific individual](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/502/why-was-my-self-help-question-closed-as-off-topic). I have also now voted to reopen the question.  It is now down to the community and/or mods to make their decisions.